# Magento 2 Custom GET REST API ready store code from url

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.2, store-id, store-code, soap-api

I have a custom REST API url:

```
<route url="/V1/vendor/module/id/:Id" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\ModuleRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

my get method the same as Magento/Catalog : `CategoryRepository`

GET URL: ...rest/en_gb/V1/vendor/module/id/1

```
public function get($id, $storeId = null )
    {
        print_r($id);//OK This prints id = 1
        print_r($storeId);die; //NOT printing `en_gb` or store id
        $cacheKey = $storeId ?? 'all';
        if (!isset($this->instances[$categoryId][$cacheKey])) {
            /** @var Category $category */
            $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
            if (null !== $storeId) {
                $category->setStoreId($storeId);
            }
            $category->load($categoryId);
            if (!$category->getId()) {
                throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField('id', $categoryId);
            }
            $this->instances[$categoryId][$cacheKey] = $category;
        }
        return $this->instances[$categoryId][$cacheKey];
    }
```

This `?storeId=1` works but it's not as is called in API Native Magento Module/Catalog:

Any Ideas Anyone? Appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class should have an instance of `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` as a dependency that will give you the current store and id.

```
private $storeManager;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    ....
}

public function get($id, $storeId = null)
{
    $storeId = $storeId ?? $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Awesome thx that works :) !

Answer (score 0):

change in xml code with this

```
<route url="/V1/vendor/module/id/:Id/store_id/:storeId" method="GET">
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\ModuleRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```